# extjs//How can I Re-rendering Absolute Panel?

Tags: extjs, rerender

I make Panel(layout:Absolute).

After, I add Items to Panel.

But I can't see that Item.

This is need Re-Render, but I don't know how to Re-Render...

Sorry to my English, but, I'm novice at English..

Thanks!

This is Absolute and Item Code

```
var centerItem = {
xtype : 'image', 
src : "lib/Image/Paddle.png",
x : 100, 
y : 100
```

};

```
var arrayItem = new Array();

var centerRegion = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        title : 'Center Region',
        region : 'center',
        xtype : 'panel',
        layout : 'absolute',
        margins : '5 5 0 5',
        id : 'designSpace',
        items : this.arrayItem
    });

Ext.onReady(function Startup() {

arrayItem.push(centerItem);

var Main = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
            width : '100%',
            height : 960,
            layout : 'border',
            items : [{......
```

Comment: Please post some code and specify version of ExtJs you're using

Comment: Sorry, Sha. I'll do that. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, Sorry, I use Extjs4. I forgot it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you push it afterwards and not include into definition?

But really, level of all your questions suggests that you need to read ExtJs Getting Started Guide - http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/guide/getting_started

Try to create samples they do there and believe me you will fell yourself much more comfortable.